# Can't fold YAML block in Vim after commenting it out

Tags: vim, yaml

I have a YAML file, and configured the folding of different sections for the document in the Vim editor. However, when I comment out a section, it remains unfolded, and trying to "re-fold" the section results in an `E490:No Fold found` error.

I guess the comments (`#` in this case), increased the indentation by one causing the folds to fail.

Does anyone know how I might comment a section of YAML document, yet still benefit from the automated folding of the commented out section (i.e. not having to manually select the section and fold it)?

Comment: It would help to see an actual example document.

Comment: Consider using [vi.se] for questions about Vim.